Restoring MySQL from Backed Up IBD Files
Last night, something happened to my MySQL database running on Ubuntu and no matter what I did, I could not not get it to start.  I eventually had to backup the /var/lib/mysql folder and do a full wipe and reinstall of MySQL 8.  After I reinstalled MySQL, it is loading fine.  Of course, none of my databases are there.
Aside from the backup of the folder, I do have proper backed up files from 1.5 years ago (yeah, I know.  My own fault.  Long story why I failed here, but worth noting this is a personal machine and not a word database.).
I initially imported those backups so I would have the databases existing.  I then tried, with MySQL not running, to copy the IBD files that I had saved from the mysql folder back into the correct spot.  The problem is that when I then go to check these, it is telling me "ERROR 1812 (HY000): Tablespace is missing for table DATABASE.TABLE."
Any ideas or suggestions?  I've been struggling with this for 4 hours thus far.
Thank you!

I believe I have solved it.  I had been trying ALTER TABLE IMPORT TABLESPACE, but what I had missed what that I needed to run CHOWN to make the user mysql the owner of the copied ibd files. Once I did CHOWN, I could then import the tablespace and it appears to be working.
